# Nlog truncate message when condition applies

Tags: nlog

In my application, I want to log any AMQP-Event published or consumed into two files. The first log-file is my "main"-file which contains various log-statemens from each layer of my application. The second log-file contains all AMQP-Events and nothing else. The events are all multi-line, each property in the event gets its own line.

Currently, the event is loggen in both files with all properties, but I would like to have only the first line in the "main" log-file and the full log-statement only in the AMQP-logfile.

Logging the AMQP-events into a seperate file works, this is my logger for that:

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="amqpEvents">
    <filters defaultAction="Ignore">
        <when condition="starts-with(message, 'Published Event')" action="Log"/>
    </filters>
</logger>
```

Now I need a way to truncate the message in the "main"-logfile. I tried using filters, but I could not find a way to truncate the message in the `action` section as it only takes an enum:

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file">
    <filters defaultAction="Log">
        <when condition="contains(message, '\r\n') and starts-with(message, 'Published Event')" action="Log"/> 
    </filters>
</logger>
```

Unfortionately, I am currently stuck on nlog 4.7, so I can't use the latest featureset.

Answer (score 0):

The NLog logging rules handles redirection of LogEvents to the wanted output targets.

The NLog target configuration handles the output formatting, and how the LogEvent is transformed into the wanted output using NLog layout.

I'm guessing your main file-target receives LogEvents from all kind of places in the application, and you want the entire LogEvent-Message from all places, except when logging AMQP-events (that has newlines).

I think you should change the lggging of AMQP-event. Either by writing 2 LogEvents with different Logger-name (And in NLog-config add `<logger name="AMQP" minLevel="Debug" final="true" />` at the top of `<rules>`)

```cs
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("AMQP").Info(payloadWithNewLines);
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("AppLog").Info(payloadForMainFile);
```

Alternative you could put the full payload into the NLog LogEventInfo.Properties-dictionary (And then use `${event-properties:AMQP}` in the layout for `amqpEvents`-target):

```cs
NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent = LogEventInfo.Create(LogLevel.Info, null, payloadForMainFile);
logEvent.Properties["AMQP"] = payloadWithNewLines;
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("AMQP").Log(logEvent);
```